# Qt application crashed once, and now cannot start even after re-installing

Tags: c++, qt, fault

I have been testing a Qt application by installing it on a few different computers. On one of them, the application crashed after clicking a button that queries a database and writes the entries to a CSV file (not sure if this is relevant to the issue).

After crashing this one time, the program will not open again.

This is the error message Windows gives:

> Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>  Application
>   Name: data-logger-interface.exe
>  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
>   Application Timestamp:    0880b74c
>  Fault Module Name: Qt5Core.dll
>   Fault Module Version: 5.3.1.0
>  Fault Module Timestamp: 777a675f
>   Exception Code:   c0000005
>  Exception Offset:  0007d187
>  OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>  Locale ID: 1033
>  Additional
>   Information 1:    0a9e
>  Additional Information
>   2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>  Additional Information
>   3:    0a9e
>  Additional Information
>   4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

So it appears to be `Qt5Core.dll` that is causing the problem. Here is more relevant information:

1. Still happens after restarting computer.
2. Still happens after uninstalling and re-installing the program.
3. Even happens to all of the older versions of the program that were previously working.
4. The program actually does work if you right click and "Start as Administrator"

Does anyone have any idea what to try next or what could possibly cause this? I know this is a broad question, but I can provide any other information on the issue.

Comment: Please show code, we still lack a "crystal ball", thanks!

Comment: "The program actually does work if you right click and 'Start as Administrator' " sounds to me like a file-permission error, are you trying some funky stuff like writing to "program files" at runtime?

Comment: Hmm, I actually do write to a file called config.txt that resides in the "program files" along with all of the other dlls.

Comment: Yeah, that's not allowed in new windows versions. Use some folder like `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation)` or `QStandardPaths::DataLocation` which usually sends you somewhere in `%APPDATA%` under Windows.

Comment: @ChrisPayne - Unless your executable is corrupted, quarantined by a virus checking program, or some other rare issue, every application starts up.  Did you debug to discover when the application actually does abort?

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and see if I can get it back up and working.

Comment: Paul, I was not able to reproduce this issue in the IDE. I do not think the executable is corrupted since all of the previous working versions suddenly stopped working as well.

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer. No need to put it in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, will do! I was not sure if it was poor etiquette to answer your own question when someone else had given the answer here in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to PeterT for figuring this out down in the comments. For anyone who experiences similar issues, I was writing some user settings to a text file. This file was generated in the actual install folder in Program Files. This caused a permission error. While it only seemed to pop up under unusual circumstances, I decided to use the QSettings class instead and this solved the problem.